# I'm unable to change states on switches inside ListItem component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-elements

What i'm trying to do is to list an array with multiple items, inside this component, and this array contains a boolean state for each individual item, like this.

```
  items : {
    "ISA InterChile" : [
      {
        key : '7843', 
        name : "ISA APP RRHH",
        fav: false
      },
      {
        key : '7844', 
        name : "Garantia y Obligaciones",
        fav: false
      },
      {
        key : '7855', 
        name : "Que se yo",
        fav: true
      },
      {
        key : '7899', 
        name : "Random",
        fav: true
      }
    ],
    "DSAC Chile" : [
      {
        key : '5022',
        name: 'ADAM RRHH',
        fav: true
      },
      {
        key : '5023',
        name: 'Name of Project 4',
        fav: false 
      }
    ],
    "Banco BCI" : [
      {
        key : '1101',
        name: 'Name of Project 3',
        fav: false
      },
      {
        key : '1014',
        name: 'Name of Project 4',
        fav: false 
      },
      {
        key : '1170',
        name: 'Name of Project 5',
        fav: false
      },
      {
        key : '1033',
        name: 'Name of Project 6',
        fav: false 
      },
      {
        key : '1101',
        name: 'Name of Project 7',
        fav: false
      },
      {
        key : '1014',
        name: 'Name of Project 8',
        fav: false 
      },
      {
        key : '1170',
        name: 'Name of Project 9',
        fav: false
      },
      {
        key : '1033',
        name: 'Name of Project 10',
        fav: false 
      }
    ]
  },
```

But whenever i try to change states, it immediately changes back to its previous state, this is the code.

```
            {
              this.state.items[this.state.SeleccionClientes].map(value => (
                <ListItem
                  containerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff', width: widthPercentageToDP('87.1%'), height: 64, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: heightPercentageToDP('2.8%'), paddingHorizontal: 0}}
                  topDivider={false}
                  bottomDivider={true}
                  titleStyle={{
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: "normal",
                    fontStyle: "normal",
                    lineHeight: 24,
                    letterSpacing: 0.15,
                    textAlign: "left",
                    color: "#707070"
                  }}
                  subtitleStyle={{
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: "normal",
                    fontStyle: "normal",
                    lineHeight: 20,
                    letterSpacing: 0.25,
                    textAlign: "left",
                    color: "#c4c4c4"
                  }}
                  title={`${value.name}`}
                  subtitle={`ID ${value.key}`}
                  switch={{
                    value: value.fav, onValueChange: () => !value.fav
                  }}
                />
              ))
            }
```

the this.state.SeleccionClientes is from a dropdown menu, where you select the item from items, and list you the items inside

EDIT: this is the whole view and code

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, StatusBar, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, RefreshControl, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import { Header, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import ModalDropdown from 'react-native-modal-dropdown';
import Images from '../../Assets/values/images';
import {
  RFPercentage as rfp,
  RFValue as rfv,
} from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
  heightPercentageToDP,
  widthPercentageToDP,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import styles from '../../Assets/values/styles/HoursReport/ClientsProyects/ClientsProyectsStyle';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import DataManager from '../../../Util/CrossUtils/DataManager';

export default class ClientsProyectsScreen extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items : {
        "ISA InterChile" : [
          {
            key : '7843', 
            name : "ISA APP RRHH",
            fav: false
          },
          {
            key : '7844', 
            name : "Garantia y Obligaciones",
            fav: false
          },
          {
            key : '7855', 
            name : "Que se yo",
            fav: true
          },
          {
            key : '7899', 
            name : "Random",
            fav: true
          }
        ],
        "DSAC Chile" : [
          {
            key : '5022',
            name: 'ADAM RRHH',
            fav: true
          },
          {
            key : '5023',
            name: 'Name of Project 4',
            fav: false 
          }
        ],
        "Banco BCI" : [
          {
            key : '1101',
            name: 'Name of Project 3',
            fav: false
          },
          {
            key : '1014',
            name: 'Name of Project 4',
            fav: true 
          },
          {
            key : '1170',
            name: 'Name of Project 5',
            fav: false
          },
          {
            key : '1033',
            name: 'Name of Project 6',
            fav: false 
          },
          {
            key : '1102',
            name: 'Name of Project 7',
            fav: true
          },
          {
            key : '1114',
            name: 'Name of Project 8',
            fav: false 
          },
          {
            key : '1175',
            name: 'Name of Project 9',
            fav: false
          },
          {
            key : '1303',
            name: 'Name of Project 10',
            fav: false 
          }
        ]
      },
      SeleccionClientes: '',
    }
  }

  updateFav = item => {
    const newData = this.state.items[this.state.SeleccionClientes];
    const uodatedItem = newData.find(x => x.key === item.key);
    uodatedItem.fav = !item.fav;
    this.setState({ data: newData });
    //You can also have a callback from parent component to update parent state
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
        <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}/>
        {/*
        <Header
          backgroundImage={Images.header_nav}
          backgroundImageStyle={styles.HeaderImagenCP}
          leftComponent={
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
              <View><Image style={styles.HeaderHorizontal} source={Images.back}/></View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
          centerComponent={{text: 'Imputar horas', ellipsizeMode: 'clip', style: styles.HeaderHoursReportCP }}
          placement='center'
        />
        */}
        <View style={styles.ContainerBackground}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginTop: heightPercentageToDP('2.2%'), marginLeft: widthPercentageToDP('6.3%')}}>
            <Text style={{
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: "500",
              fontStyle: "normal",
              lineHeight: 35,
              letterSpacing: 0,
              textAlign: "left",
              color: "#707070"
            }}>Proyectos</Text>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{position: 'absolute', alignItems: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end', paddingBottom: heightPercentageToDP('0.5%'), left: widthPercentageToDP('90%')}} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
            <Image source={Images.close_modal}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
          enableOnAndroid={true}>
            {/*
            <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginRight: widthPercentageToDP('6.3%')}}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                <Image source={Images.close_modal}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            */}
            <View style={styles.Left}>
              <Text style={styles.TituloInputOnBlur}>Cliente</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.Center}>
              <ModalDropdown
                dropdownTextStyle={styles.dropdownTextStyle}
                dropdownTextHighlightStyle={styles.dropdownTextHighlightStyle}
                defaultValue={'Seleccionar'}
                style={styles.dropStyle}
                textStyle={{
                  padding: 0,
                  margin: 0,
                  fontSize: rfv(16),
                  paddingVertical: hp('1.2%'),
                  fontWeight: 'normal',
                  fontStyle: 'normal',
                  textAlign: 'left',
                  //color: Motivo != 'Seleccionar' ? '#1a1a1a' : '#c4c4c4',
                }}
                onSelect={(index, value) => this.setState({SeleccionClientes: value})}
                options={Object.keys(this.state.items)}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
            {
              this.state.SeleccionClientes !== '' ?
              <View>
                {
                  <FlatList
                    data={this.state.items[this.state.SeleccionClientes]}
                    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                      <ListItem
                        containerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa', width: widthPercentageToDP('87.1%'), height: 64, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: heightPercentageToDP('2.8%'), paddingHorizontal: 0}}
                        topDivider={false}
                        bottomDivider={true}
                        titleStyle={{
                          marginLeft: 0,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: "normal",
                          fontStyle: "normal",
                          lineHeight: 24,
                          letterSpacing: 0.15,
                          textAlign: "left",
                          color: "#707070"
                        }}
                        subtitleStyle={{
                          marginLeft: 0,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: "normal",
                          fontStyle: "normal",
                          lineHeight: 20,
                          letterSpacing: 0.25,
                          textAlign: "left",
                          color: "#c4c4c4"
                        }}
                        title={`${item.name}`}
                        subtitle={`ID ${item.key}`}
                        switch={{
                          //trackColor: {false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff"},
                          //thumbColor: item.fav ? "#1062cc" : "#f4f3f4",
                          value: item.fav[index], 
                          onValueChange: () => {this.updateFav(item)}
                        }}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                }
              </View>
              :
              <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                <View style={{marginTop: heightPercentageToDP('11%')}}>
                  <Image style={{marginBottom: heightPercentageToDP('2.8%')}} source={Images.sad_face}/>
                </View>
                <Text style={{
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: "normal",
                  fontStyle: "normal",
                  lineHeight: 35,
                  letterSpacing: 0,
                  textAlign: "left",
                  color: "#c4c4c4"
                }}>Sin proyectos activos</Text>
              </View>
            }
            </View>
          <View style={styles.BottomPush} />
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the state, your switch takes the value from the state object. And better use a flat list instead of map as its good in terms of performance. This will be a sample approach that you can take.

```
class CustomFlatList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data,
    };
  }

  updateFav = item => {
    const newData = [...this.state.data];
    const uodatedItem = newData.find(x => x.key === item.key);
    uodatedItem.fav = !item.fav;
    this.setState({ data: newData });
    //You can also have a callback from parent component to update parent state
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem
            title={`${item.name}`}
            subtitle={`ID ${item.key}`}
            switch={{
              value: item.fav,
              onValueChange: () => this.updateFav(item),
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

--Updated code after full code

You will have to update the updateFav function as below.

```
 updateFav = item => {
        const newData = [...this.state.items[this.state.SeleccionClientes]];
        const updateItem = newData.find(x => x.key === item.key);
        updateItem.fav = !item.fav;

        const updatedArray = Object.assign(this.state.items);
        updatedArray[this.state.SeleccionClientes] = newData;
        this.setState({ items: updatedArray });
    };
```

Comment: wait a min, you're not using the updatedItem.fav, btw, i'm getting an error whenever i click a state

Comment: i dont see a definition for updatedItem.fav and can you share the error that you are getting ?

Comment: getting a "TypeError: invalid attempt to update non-iterable instance"

Comment: what the value of your this.props.data ?

Comment: the array i showed you in my question, the items array

Comment: try this <CustomFlatList data={this.state.items[this.state.SeleccionClientes]} /> the problem is your items is an object not an array so when trying to expand that you get the above error, so give an array to custom flat list i've given, it will work

Comment: how can i implement this without calling a custom component like yours? i think it'll be easier

Comment: you have to update your state when the onValueChange of switch, pass a callback function from parent to update the state

Comment: And you dont have to use a custom component , i just gave a sample so that you can do this in your code

Comment: ok i managed to implement the customflatlist the way you made it, but the states are not getting saved

Comment: Can you update the above code with a full component ? then its easy to give a solution

Comment: i added the entire view

Comment: sorry i edited once more, i accidentally put a different screen, should be there now

Comment: i'm getting, TypeError: invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214117/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-nicolas-silva).

Comment: it works !! thanks a lot dude, i really appreciate your work and time